# Clicking on child does not trigger parent click

Tags: javascript

When clicking on `content` I want to trigger my `alert`.
I could have any number of child elements in my `content` so I don't want to hardcode every single one. I thought that maybe I could listen for clicks on that parent element and then every click on child would trigger my action. But it doesn't work.

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var content = document.getElementById('content');

wrapper.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  if (e.target === content  ) {
 alert('clicked!');
} 
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <span>HELLO!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `console.log(e.target);` to see what it logs! ;)

Comment: I guess you could traverse up the DOM tree using var element.parentNode and check if this parentNode is the `content` and if it is, just fire the alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentNode to traverse the DOM:

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');    
var content = document.getElementById('content');

wrapper.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  while(target.parentNode && target!==content) {target=target.parentNode;}

  if (target === content) {
    alert('clicked!');
  } 
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <span>HELLO!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Note: This only makes sense if there are other things to click on in #wrapper. Otherwise you can just attach a click event to #content without checking the target, since the event bubbles up anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code based on my comment. You can just traverse up the tree and check for content element.

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var content = document.getElementById('content');

wrapper.addEventListener("click",function(e) {

  var element = e.target;

  while(element.parentNode) {
    
    if (element === content  ) {
      alert('clicked!');
      break;
    } 

    element = element.parentNode;

  }

});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <span>HELLO!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the best would be to just add an event listener to the content element without any condition like so:

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var content = document.getElementById('content');

content.addEventListener("click",function(e) {

  alert('clicked!');

});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <span>HELLO!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the note, it works now, just by moving the if statement above the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:white">
  <div id="content" style="background-color:gray">
    <div>HELLO!</div>
    <div>WHUUUHUUU</div>
  </div>

  <div id="dontTrigger">
    <span>DONT!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var content = document.getElementById('content');

content.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    alert('clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

event.target is precisely the dom on which click has been done.In this case the span is the target.
If you are free to jquery, you can use closest method which selects the closest parent(including self) matching the selector:

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var content = document.getElementById('content');

wrapper.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('#content')[0]) {
 alert('clicked!');
} 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <span>HELLO!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: without jQuery plz as OP has tagged only **javascript**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want every child of the `#wrapper` element to fire a function on click I would suggest doing it this way :

#### HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:white">
    <div id="content" style="background-color:gray">
        <div>HELLO!</div>
        <div>WHUUUHUUU</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JS :

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var contentNodes = wrapper.children;
for (var i = 0; i < contentNodes.length; i++)
{
    contentNodes[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert('clicked !');
    });
}
```

this way, you can also determine which element was clicked through the variable `this` inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is CSS pointer events. You can turn off pointer events on the child elements so the click only registers on the parent.

`#wrapper > * { pointer-events: none; }`